# Can you create an account with a non-native asset

Tags: assets

Is it possible to fund an account with a non-native asset? I have been following the documentation here: https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/get-started/create-account.html which uses the friendbot to fund the account. However, if I have an issuing account can I use that to fund the account?

Also, in line with that do I need to establish trust in the transaction as well, or does that have to be done first?

Answer (score 2):

You can not create a stellar account with non-native assets,

> Also, in line with that do I need to establish trust in the
>   transaction as well, or does that have to be done first?

Account must trust your assets before the transaction

> each account must have a minimum balance of 1 lumen

Answer (score 0):

you cannot. the stellar account has to have XLM in escrow depending on how many offers and assets the customer holds. 0.5 each. And you have to be funded with minimum balance in order to create assets